# Can we get a "black flag" tag synonym for Assassin's Creed 4?

Tags: support, tag-synonyms

We have an [assassins-creed-4](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/assassins-creed-4) tag, but lots of people are going to be typing `black flag` and aren't going to find the correct tag. I don't have enough rep in the tag to suggest a synonym. Could we get [ac-4-black-flag](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ac-4-black-flag) or [ac-black-flag](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ac-black-flag) added as a synonym for discoverability?

(`assassins-creed-4-black-flag` and `assassins-creed-black-flag` are both too long.)

Comment: I'd say synonymize both based on my answer [here.](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/5576/how-should-we-tag-assassins-creed-3-liberation/5582#5582)

Comment: @Fluttershy Ideally, yes! I don't know what [this user actually typed](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/posts/138601/revisions) such that they thought we didn't already have the tag, but as much coverage as possible should be in place before it releases on more platforms. (It's nice of them to do a limited release so that we can iron out our tags before the question flood starts. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now that we have a 35 character limit for tag names, I think a better solution would be to rename [assassins-creed-4](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/assassins-creed-4) to [assassins-creed-4-black-flag](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/assassins-creed-4-black-flag).

Update: Thanks @Robotnik for taking care of this!

Comment: Rename is done, may as well update your answer :-)